# Show that $(\sqrt{2}-1)^n$ is irrational

Tags: elementary-number-theory, exponentiation, radicals, rationality-testing

> Show that for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ the number $(\sqrt{2}-1)^n$ is irrational.

I do not get the idea of the proof at all, any help appreaciated.

edit: I am also thinking whether it will be possible to show $(\sqrt{2}-1)^n=\sqrt{m+1}-\sqrt{m}$

Comment: What was the proof that you did not get?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since 
$$
(\sqrt{2}-1)^n=\frac{1}{(\sqrt{2}+1)^n}
$$
it is enougth to prove that $(\sqrt{2}+1)^n$ is irrrational.
We have after direct calculation  that 
$$
(\sqrt{2}+1)^n=a+b \sqrt{2}, 
$$
for some  natural   $a,b,$  $b\neq 0.$
Suppose now that $(\sqrt{2}+1)^n$ is rational. It  follows  that 
$\sqrt{2}$ is also rational since 
$$
\sqrt{2}=\frac{1}{b}((\sqrt{2}+1)^n-a).
$$
We obtain  a contradiction so 
 $(\sqrt{2}-1)^n$ is an irrational number.

Comment: well, you are right, but since $\sqrt{2}-1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}+1}}$ it is enouth  that $\sqrt{2}+1}$ is rational. Then $b \neq 0.$

Comment: Can't we just show that (\sqrt{2}-1)^n-\sqrt{m}?

Comment: I have explained it in main text

Comment: Proving that $b\ne0$ is exactly the problem. You can't say $b\ne0$ without proving it.

Comment: I dont see any problem. If $\sqrt{2}>0, 1>0$ then $a>0$  and $b>0$, it is easy to prove.

Comment: @egreg: The point of going to +1 instead of -1 was that all terms in the expansion becomes positive, and the sum therefore has to be positive. This is fairly obvious but should perhaps have been explicitely stated.

Answer (score 4):

Note that if we set $a=1-\sqrt 2$ and $b=1+\sqrt 2$ we have $a+b=2$ and $ab=-1$, so that $a,b$ are roots of the quadratic $x^2-2x-1=0$, and $(ab)^n=(-1)^n$.

Now note that $a^2-2a-1=0$ can be multiplied by $a^n$ to obtain the equation $a^{n+2}=2a^{n+1}+a^n$. If we add the equivalent equation for $b^{n+2}$ and set $u_n=a^n+b^n$ we find that $$u_{n+2}=2u_{n+1}+u_n$$

Since $u_0=u_1=2$ the $u_n$ are increasing positive (even) integers and $a^n$ and $b^n$ are roots of $x^2-u_nx+(-1)^n=0$.

Now apply the rational root theorem.

Answer (score 2):

$(\sqrt{2}-1)^n$ can be written as $p(n) + q(n)\sqrt{2}$, with both $p(n)$ and $q(n)$ integers, with $q(n)\neq0$.

Comment: $q(n)\ne0$ is exactly what's to be proved. Induction should suffice.

Answer (score 2):

Let a vector $[x\ y]^T$, $x,y \in \mathbb{Q}$ represent a number of the form $x + \sqrt{2}y$. Multiplying by $(\sqrt{2} - 1)$ then corresponds to applying the matrix
$$ A = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 2 \\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}. $$

Multiplying by $(\sqrt{2} - 1)^n$ corresponds to applying $A^n$.

Suppose $(\sqrt{2} - 1)^n = r \in \mathbb{Q}$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. That would mean that $A^n = rI$. We show that it is impossible.

$A$, considered as a real matrix, has two distinct eigenvalues: $\pm\sqrt{2} - 1$. Thus, $A^n$ also has two distinct eigenvalues: $(\pm\sqrt{2} - 1)^n$. But then it can't be of the form $rI$.